# UWP app crashes rarely with Exception code 0xc000027b in windows 1803 version only

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Application works fine. But sometimes app crashes unexpectedly in windows 1803 version alone. Without logging the error,it crashes with exception code 0xc000027b.

Comment: Without seeing the code that throws the exception, there's very little we can do to help except for Google (or whatever your favourite search engine is) the exception and windows version, which presumably you've already done.

Comment: Does the issue could be in my application or windows system?

Comment: No idea, depends what the code that throws it does.